# Md5 all info in a mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i have a login script and a register script but im storing the users password has a plain word. Is there any way to md5 all the result in my user table ? I have a user table with 1200 results and i want to update all results and md5 all the password columns. Last time i tried i updated them all to md5 but everyone had the same password has each other.

Would

```
UPDATE `newtoxic`.`users` SET `password` = MD5; work ?
```

I know

```
UPDATE `newtoxic`.`users` SET `password` = MD5( 'therepasswordgoeshere' );
```

Works but i can;t go though each and everyone of them updating 1 by 1 ...

Comment: `MD5`ing your passwords is not so much better than leaving them plaintext - read up on salts and hash functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
UPDATE `newtoxic`.`users` SET `password` = MD5(`password`);
```

(Make sure your password column is large enough to hold the whole thing).

Comment: Remember to update your php scripts to test against the md5 passwords also... :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the literal password, just pass the name of your password field.

```
UPDATE newtoxic.users SET password = MD5( password)
```